# Deleted width styling, still not changing. jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

EDIT: If I style width the input to a pixel it will change the size but if I try and do it to a percentage it doesn't change. I have other inputs in the same div that change size on percentage but not with the classes typeahead and tt-query

I have this script I found and I've gotten it to work. The issue is when I try and make it responsive I can't change the width of the input box or dropdown.

the CSS

```
        <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        name: 'typeahead',
        remote:'../searchchem.php?key=%QUERY',
        limit : 10
    });
});
    </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .bs-example{
            font-family: sans-serif;
            position: relative;
            margin: 5px;
            }
            .typeahead, .tt-query, .tt-hint {
            border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
            border-radius: 8px;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 30px;
            padding: 8px 20px;
            }
            .typeahead {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            }
            .typeahead:focus {
            border: 2px solid #0097CF;
            }
            .tt-query {
            box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
            }
            .tt-hint {
            color: #999999;
            }
            .tt-dropdown-menu {
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            border-radius: 8px;
            box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            margin-top: 12px;
            padding: 8px 0;
            }
            .tt-suggestion {
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 24px;
            padding: 3px 20px;
            }
            .tt-suggestion.tt-is-under-cursor {
            background-color: #0097CF;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            }
            .tt-suggestion p {
            margin: 0;
            }

</style>
```

THE HTML

```
<form action="search.php" method="post">
                                            <input type="text" name="typeahead" class="form-control typeahead tt-query" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Type your Query">
                                            <input type="submit" value="Search">
                                        </form>
```

The Jquery

```
https://jsfiddle.net/fet3vuc0/
```

I apologize in advance for jquery being on one line, i'm not sure how to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are seeing is the initial width of the element given by your browser. If you strip your form bare so it only has the text input and button, the text input will still have an initial width, slightly different across browser. But that width will not adjust if you change the width of the browser window.

Normally with responsive, you'd set styles with [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). This allows you to give a different width depending on your size of browser window.

Note that IE8 and lower IE versions do not support Media Queries.

**UPDATE**

With your update to your question:

Try using [box-sizing](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) on your text input.

Comment: It seems as if you are right. I didn't try to set the input style to pixels, just a percentage. It isn't working as a percentage even though it's within a div where other inputs are styled with a width percentage and working. Updated question

Comment: You answered it! The answer was in that article. `padding: 8px 20px;` I had to make adjustments of the padding with percentages to change it!